# Is there a way to use dots as tabspaces?

Tags: python

So lets say I have a function where I print a numbered list, all is good until the index becomes double digits. if the list is long enough, it wont be formatted as neatly as it could. So the obvious thing to do would be seperate the data from the number with a tab. But just for simplicities sake, is it possible to fill the blank space taken up with the tab space with dots (as is sometimes seen in lists with large distances between the value and number)

Heres what I got.

```py
print('\n--Shopping List--')
        with open("ShoppingList.txt","r") as lst:
            for index, data in enumerate(lst, start=1):
                print("{}. {}".format(index, data),end='')
            print()
```

The output of this is:

```
--Shopping List--
1. item1
2. item2
3. item3
4. item4
5. item5
6. item6
7. item7
8. item8
9. item9
10. item10
11. item11
12. item12
13. item13
14. item14
15. item15
```

as you can see the items get pushed out at the double digits.

The desired output would look like this

```
--Shopping List--
1....item1
2....item2
3....item3
4....item4
5....item5
6....item6
7....item7
8....item8
9....item9
10...item10
11...item11
12...item12
13...item13
14...item14
15...item15
```

In short: I want something that works like `\t` but instead of giving me whitespace, gives me dots. Is there a simple way to do this that doesnt involve a bunch of math calculating the amount of dots I need?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.ljust(n, char)`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to the rescue:

```
>>> for n, text in enumerate(["foo", "bar", "baz"]):
...     print(f"{str(n).ljust(4, '.')}{text}")
...
0...foo
1...bar
2...baz
```

Alternately, [using modern format strings](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align),

```
>>> for n, text in enumerate(["foo", "bar", "baz"]):
...     print(f"{n:.<4}{text}")
...
0...foo
1...bar
2...baz
```

Comment: To be absolutely safe in case the numbers go into the thausands or even bigger, you can also get `n` before the loop using `n = len(str(len(lst)))+1` or (a bit more fancy) `math.floor(math.log10(len(lst))+2)`

Comment: Yep – though OP said "that doesnt involve a bunch of math calculating the amount of dots I need" ;-)

Comment: Yeah but this is a shopping list and its in python, its not really intended to handle large lists of items. but that would totally work in the case i have a shopping list thousands of elements long

Answer (score 0):

Given data.dat:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
item9
item10
item11
```

Then:

```
with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()

for i, x in enumerate(data):
    istr = "{:.<5}".format(i)
    print(istr + x)
```

Output:

```
0....item1
1....item2
2....item3
3....item4
4....item5
5....item6
6....item7
7....item8
8....item9
9....item10
10...item11
```

Comment: Instead of `replace()` you can use `{:.<5}` to pad the string with `.` instead of spaces.

Comment: Thanks @white it has been edited

Comment: @Synthase cant upvote as i dont have enough reputation yet, and i've already accepted another answer. This answer is not wrong, but it fit my needs better.